# See file size on wireshark when downloading

Tags: networking, wireshark, headers, packet

Is there a way to see the filesize of a file when starting a download through wireshark?

I want to see the size of http downloads on wireshark when i start them but i cant find that information.

Answer (score 1):

With an HTTP download, the file size is provided by the HTTP response header's "Content-Length" field.

For more info on the Content-Length field check out this StackOverflow question:

[What's the “Content-Length” field in HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header)

As for viewing it in WireShark...

> Add "Content-Length" as a column:
>
> - Right-click on the "Content-Length" header in the packet details pane.
> - Choose "Apply as Column".

Source: AskWireshark.com's [How to display HTTP Header Length in bytes as a column?](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/3574/how-to-display-http-header-length-in-bytes-as-a-column):

Comment: I added it but i dont see anything relativve to the actual download size.